# Variance between two random points

Tags: uniform-distribution

I have a circle centred at $(0,0)$ with radius $r$ and I have $2$ random points $P$ and $Q$ on the circumference of the circle. If $d$ is the distance between $P$ and $Q$, what is the variance of $d$?

My solution:
I have taken $P$ with coordinates $(x_1,y_2)$ and $Q$ with coordinates $(x_2,y_2)$

$d=2r \sin(\frac{\theta}{2})$ as it is the equation of chord length.

I have the joint pdf of $x$ and $y$ as :

$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{\pi r^2}$ if $(x,y)$ is on the circle.

$f(x,y)=0$ otherwise.

Will the intergal of $xf(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ and $y$ , give me the expected value of $d$?

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Answer (score 1):

That’s not a proper probability density function; it’s only defined on a set of measure zero, and its integral is zero.

You can use the fact that the angle $\theta$ is uniformly distributed, so the expected chord length is

$$
\left\langle d\right\rangle=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}2r\sin\frac\theta2\mathrm d\theta=\frac{2r}\pi\left[-\cos\frac\theta2\right]_0^{2\pi}=\frac4\pi r\;.
$$

and the expected value of its square is

$$
\left\langle d^2\right\rangle=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\left(2r\sin\frac\theta2\right)^2\mathrm d\theta=2r^2\;,
$$

so the variance is

$$
\operatorname{Var} d=\left\langle d^2\right\rangle-\left\langle d\right\rangle^2=2r^2-\left(\frac4\pi r\right)^2=\left(2-\left(\frac4\pi\right)^2\right)r^2\approx0.379r^2\;.
$$

Comment: will the expected value of x^2 be :$$
\frac1{4\pi^2}\int_0^{2\pi}2r\sin\frac\theta2\mathrm d\theta$$

Comment: @caston1414: I'm not sure why you want the expected value of $x^2$ – for the variance of $d$ you need the expected value of $d^2$. I've added the variance calculation to the answer.